# Ng-click and ng-show AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json, angularjs

I have a list of dictionaries, and I want to toggle show all the students and their details for each classroom.

This is the HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<div class="classrooms-details" ng-show="Students">
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
         <tr>
          <th>First name</th>
          <th>Last name</th>
          <th>Gender</th>
          <th>Birthday</th>
         </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
     <tr ng-repeat="classroom in classrooms">
       <td>{{classroom.student.first_name}}</a></td>
       <td>{{classroom.student.last_name}}</td>
       <td>{{classroom.student.gender}}</td>
       <td>{{classroom.student.birthday}}</td>
      </tr>
     </tbody>
     </table>
</div>

<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
     <tr>
      <th>Classroom</th>
      <th>School</th>
      <th>Academic year</th>
     </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
     <tr ng-repeat="classroom in classrooms">
       <td><a href="#" ng-click="showStudents">{{classroom.classroom}}</a></td>
       <td>{{classroom.school.school_name}}</td>
       <td>{{classroom.academic_year}}</td>
      </tr>
     </tbody>
   </table>

</div>
```

I've tried to use ng-click/ng-show, but it's not working.

And this is the script:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.classrooms = [{
        "school": {
            "id": 1,
            "school_name": "IPSIA F. Lampertico",
            "address": "Viale Giangiorgio Trissino, 30",
            "city": "Vicenza"
        },
        "academic_year": "2015/2016",
        "classroom": "1^A",
        "floor": 0,
        "students": [{
            "classroom": 1,
            "first_name": "Stefano",
            "last_name": "Rossi",
            "gender": "M",
            "birthday": "1998-06-22"
        }, {
            "classroom": 1,
            "first_name": "Luca",
            "last_name": "Possanzini",
            "gender": "M",
            "birthday": "1999-11-22"
        }]
    }, {
        "school": {
            "id": 2,
            "school_name": "ITIS A. Rossi",
            "address": "Via Legione Gallieno, 52",
            "city": "Vicenza"
        },
        "academic_year": "2015/2016",
        "classroom": "2^B",
        "floor": 0,
        "students": [{
            "classroom": 2,
            "first_name": "Sergio",
            "last_name": "Lazzari",
            "gender": "M",
            "birthday": "2001-01-29"
        }]
    }];
    console.log($scope.classrooms);
});
```

I don't know how to access "students" values, and I'd like the students details to be shown only when clicking on the classroom name.

How could I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to set a specific classroom as the "active" classroom and display the students within. The easiest way to do this would be something like:

**View**

```
<tr ng-if="activeClassroom" ng-repeat="student in activeClassroom.students">
  <td>{{student.first_name}}</a></td>
  <td>{{student.last_name}}</td>
  <td>{{student.gender}}</td>
  <td>{{student.birthday}}</td>
</tr>
```

...

```
<tr ng-repeat="classroom in classrooms">
  <td><a href="#" ng-click="setActiveClassroom(classroom)">{{classroom.classroom}}</a></td>
  <td>{{classroom.school.school_name}}</td>
  <td>{{classroom.academic_year}}</td>
</tr>
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.activeClassroom = null;

$scope.setActiveClassroom = function (classroom) {
  $scope.activeClassroom = classroom;
};
```

Comment: Great answer! Thank you :)